# How to bind canvas dimension in WPF when zoom out using RenderTransform

Tags: wpf, canvas

Here is my canvas in XAML:

```
<TabItem Name="tabPlanView" Header=" Graphics " Background="White">
            <Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-2,-1,-2,1" ClipToBounds="True">

                <Grid>
                    <Canvas Name="mainCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#FF061D30" MouseWheel="mainCanvas_MouseWheel" MouseDown="canvasDrawing_MouseDown" MouseMove="canvasDrawing_MouseMove" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MouseLeave="mainCanvas_MouseLeave" >
                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>

                                <ScaleTransform  x:Name="st" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />

                        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

                    </Canvas>
                    <Image x:Name="img_Axis" MouseMove="canvasDrawing_MouseMove" Height="100" Source="pack://application:,,,/images/axisss.gif" Margin="10,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>

            </Border>
        </TabItem>
```

and here is its MouseWheel event in code behind:

```
var element = sender as UIElement;
        var position = e.GetPosition(element);
        var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        var scale = e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); 

        matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;
```

In the image below, when I zoom out the canvas boundaries and its parent (CanvasBorder) boundaries do not match.

[image]

I tried LayoutTransform instead. It works but it cannot make a flexible zoom in relation to the mouse position (only some fixed zooming in relation to left bottom corner at all).

I need a zoomable canvas with bounded dimensions to its border and flexible wheel zoom in relation to mouse positions.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning

Comment: Thank you Clemens. It is a really good solution.